# Etymology of "salarium" and its connection to salt

Tags: etymology, noun, english, spanish

It has been asked before both in the English Language & Usage site and the Spanish Language site about the etymology of *[salary](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/448865/280768)* and *[salario](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26500/12637)*, respectively. In both cases, this site was mentioned as a more suitable place to ask this question, but it seems it has not been asked already.

Some texts say that the Latin word *salarium* comes from *sal* "because the Roman Legions were sometimes paid in salt". Or maybe they were paid to buy salt. A Spanish dictionary from 1611 (by Sebastián de Covarrubias) states that *salt* in this case must be understood as any type of food, as *salt* was added to almost any meal, so a *salary* was something you could buy food with. It also says that the reason could have something to do with the rents obtained with the salt marshes.

In any case, the question is: when and how did the word *salarium* originate in the Latin language? Does its etymology come from Latin *sal*? If so, what is its actual connection with the salt?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112112481541;view=1up;seq=185) suggests:

> SALARY, salaire, F. From *salarium*, L. a stated
>   allowance of provisions given to a soldier, of which (*sal*)
>   salt was a necessary part; and hence the term came to signify pay or *salary*.

[This other book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.hn5x1e;view=1up;seq=62) suggests:

> SALARY. Of or belonging to salt. Money given
>   to the soldiers for salt. (L. *salarium*.) (A. L.) [Andrew's Latin Lexicon]
>
> Salt was held in great veneration by the ancients. It was always
>   used in sacrifices; thus also Moses ordained, —
>   "With all thine offerings thou shalt offer salt." *Lev.ii.13.*
>
> Thus, to set salt before a stranger was, and still is, by
>   some Eastern nations reckoned a symbol of friendship; and
>   to  spill the salt at table was esteemed ominous.
>   The desire to obtain means for the purchase of salt
>   gave rise to the word *salarium*, salary.
>   (A. R. A., p. 312.) [Adam's Roman Antiquities]

[This book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015050683476;view=1up;seq=120) states:

> Whenever  a word loses a definite denotation, its meaning
>   is obviously generalized or diffused. Because people think
>   with varying degrees of definiteness, we find an almost inexhaustible
>   number of examples of generalization or blurring of meaning. For example,
>   salary comes from the Latin *salarium*, 'salt money,' part of pay of the
>   Roman soldiers. **Ignorance and the lack of literacy have contributed their full share to linguistic change.** Many of the words we use today
>   retain the fossils of the past; we can see in them forgotten uses and
>   customs.

[This book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=iau.31858000366918;view=1up;seq=323) has an interesting entry too. When listing words with the same origin  but that are apparently so different (p.305), the following list about words derived from *sal* is included:

> 27. *Sauce* (L. salsus, Fr. sauce), *saucer* (Sp. salsera, Fr. sauciere) and
>       *sausage* (Sp. salchicha, Fr. saucisse), *salsify* and *salad* (Sp. salado, salted), and *saline* and *salary* (L. salarium, lit. salt-money given to
>       the soldiers, or a stipend) are all derived from L. sal, salt (Sk, sara-s,
>       Gr. &Ag); as well as *insular* (= in sale).

On this same issue, [this book](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015050683476;view=1up;seq=252) states:

> 104. *sal*, *salis*, salt; stem, *sal-*, *sali-*
>
> Related words: saline, salad, sauce, sausage, saltpeter, salary, saucer, saucy.
>
> *Salary* is from *salarium*, 'salt money paid a soldier.' A
>   *saucer* was a receptacle for *sauce* from *salsus*, 'salty,' which
>   is derived from *sal*. A *saucy* person is one whose talk is 'salted,'
>   sharp, or pert. *Sausage* comes through Late Latin *salsicia* from
>   Latin *salsus*, 'salty.'

(so sausage comes from *sal* too! Who would have thought that!)

Comment: Salt is a natural food preservative and flavor enhancer: it added value to food, AND was scarce in ancient Europe. That is why it's paralleled with gold (think of German _Geld_ meaning money)

Comment: Spanish _salchicha_ 'sausage' comes from Italian _salciccia_, probably from Late Latin _salsicia_, from _salsus_ 'salty'.

Comment: @Charlie (yes; see last quote in the answer!)

Comment: Yes, what I meant is that Spanish and Italian words for 'sausage' also come from Latin _salsus_. :-)

Comment: @Charlie Oh, sorry! I didn't get that. Yes, that's interesting too!

Comment: “ Ignorance and the lack of literacy have contributed their full share to linguistic change.” Surely you don’t believe that?!